# How to decompose the following circuit using just CX and U3 gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, quantum-state

I am trying to decompose the following circuit using just the CX gate and U3 gate.
[image]

This is because IBM uses CX and U3 gates as basis states and trying to understand the same. Is there a function that decomposes based on the backend configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis gate set of IBM quantum devices was $\{\text{CX}, \text{U3}\}$ but this has been changed. The current basis gate set for IBM quantum devices is available in the [device catalog](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources?tab=systems):

[image]

Programmatically, you can get the basis gate set for a backend as follows:

```
backend.configuration().basis_gates
```

And to compile the input circuit to some target backend, use [`transpile()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html) method

```
transpiled_circuit = transpile(original_circuit, backend=backend)
```

---

**Update**

If all what you want is to expand the gates in your circuit into one- and two-qubit gates you can use [`QuantumCircuit.decompose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html). By default, `decompose()` method does a shallow decomposition, that is, decomposes one level only. You can pass `reps` parameter for iterative decomposition.

```
decomposed_circuit = original_circuit.decompose(reps=3)
```

You can still use `transpile()` method in this case but instead of passing `backend` parameter, you specify the basis gate set using `basis_gates` parameter:

```
transpiled_circuit = transpile(original_circuit, basis_gates=['cx', 'u'], optimization_level=3)
```

In addition to decomposing the gates and transforming them into the gate set you want, `transpile` will optimize your circuit.

```
print('Decomposed circuit depth:', decomposed_circuit.depth())
print('Transpiled circuit depth:', transpiled_circuit.depth())
```

Comment: do i set optimization_level=0 to remove any mapping or routing? Also would backend affect anything if I transpile and set the basis gate to U3 and CX?